# liquid simulation that sticks to a surface effect

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've been trying to simulate a golden metallic liquid that originates from a golden mask.
I have almost got the simulation ready but I cant seem to find any setting that makes the liquid stick to the surface and emit slowly (kind of like a lava lamp). I want it to look like the concept art in the attachment, with the liquid being very random and fine strings of fluid. If any of you can recommend any setting on how this could work or any tutorials I would be very grateful, because I've been at this for hours and couldn't find a solution yet.

Greetings,
C.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a Mantaflow Fluid simulation? If yes, have you tried to use a Force Field? (example: https://youtu.be/hMh0pyMt1YE). Alternatively, you can try Geometry Nodes (Simulation Nodes), something like: https://youtu.be/qpt8aWNZfYk or https://youtu.be/qaT3xFe7QMo, search for "light trails"

Comment: The first tutorial was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!